# Flat File to SQL server

Tags: sql-server, external-tables, charindex, string-function

I want to read data from a TXT/FLAT file and arrange the data using the first column contents as column names and the data after the semi colon as records .

SAMPLE DATA

```
{1:F01SBZAZAJJXXXX9999999999}{2:I940SBICMWMXXXXXN}{4:
:20:D424A100110011E4
:25:020083203
:28C:49/1
:60F:C140106ZAR1029873,62
:61:1401060106DR5000,NTRF99999999//NONREF20140106-13175-016050001844421
:86:/PREF/ZA000520CATS THIRD PARTY PAYMENT
:62F:C140106ZAR0,00
-}

{1:F01SBZAZAJJXXXX9999999999}{2:I940SBICMWMXXXXXN}{4:
:20:D3DE7040110011E4
:25:020083204
:28C:51/1
:60F:C140106NAD1030073,
:61:1401060106DR5000,NTRF20140106-13175-0//NONREF20140106-13175-016050001844421
:86:/PREF/NA000520TRANSFER
:62F:C140106NAD0,00
-}
```

The query below only worked for one chunk...I need a query that reads the whole data set and arranges it as shown above in the attached image.

```sql
SELECT [20], [25], [28C], [60F], [61], [86], [62F] 
FROM
(SELECT column2, column3 FROM [dbo].[Sample MT940]) AS Source_Table
PIVOT
(MAX(column3)
FOR 
column2 in ([20], [25], [28C], [60F], [61], [86], [62F])
) AS PIVOT_TABLE
```

Expected Results

[image: Expected results]

Comment: I imported the data from a txt file  and  the result was as shown on SAMPLE DATA section

Comment: GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sample_MT940](
 [column1] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sample_MT940]
           ([column1])
     VALUES
           (<column1, nvarchar(100),>)
GO

Comment: SQL is probably not the best tool for this job.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft What tool do you have in mind?

Comment: Either some tool that understands that file format, or a procedural programming language that has better text parsing capabilities, like python, C#, etc.

Comment: Do you always have  full set of values for each row in the target table: **([20], [25], [28C], [60F], [61], [86], [62F])**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

The assumption is that you always have full set of values for each row in the target table: ([20], [25], [28C], [60F], [61], [86], [62F])

We are grouping all rows into buckets with 9 consecutive rows in each of them via `NTILE()` function.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (Token VARCHAR(1024));
INSERT @tbl (Token) VALUES
('{1:F01SBZAZAJJXXXX9999999999}{2:I940SBICMWMXXXXXN}{4:'),
(':20:D424A100110011E4'),
(':25:020083203'),
(':28C:49/1'),
(':60F:C140106ZAR1029873,62'),
(':61:1401060106DR5000,NTRF99999999//NONREF20140106-13175-016050001844421'),
(':86:/PREF/ZA000520CATS THIRD PARTY PAYMENT'),
(':62F:C140106ZAR0,00'),
('-}'),
('{1:F01SBZAZAJJXXXX9999999999}{2:I940SBICMWMXXXXXN}{4:'),
(':20:D3DE7040110011E4'),
(':25:020083204'),
(':28C:51/1'),
(':60F:C140106NAD1030073,'),
(':61:1401060106DR5000,NTRF20140106-13175-0//NONREF20140106-13175-016050001844421'),
(':86:/PREF/NA000520TRANSFER'),
(':62F:C140106NAD0,00'),
('-}');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @group INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tbl) / 9

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT * 
        , _token = PARSENAME(REPLACE(token,':','.'),1)
        , seq = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) % 9
        , grp = NTILE(@group) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT DISTINCT [20] = MAX(IIF(seq = 2, _token, '')) OVER (PARTITION BY grp)
    , [25] = MAX(IIF(seq = 3, _token, '')) OVER (PARTITION BY grp)
    , [28C] = MAX(IIF(seq = 4, _token, '')) OVER (PARTITION BY grp)
    , [60F] = MAX(IIF(seq = 5, _token, '')) OVER (PARTITION BY grp)
    , [61] = MAX(IIF(seq = 6, _token, '')) OVER (PARTITION BY grp)
    , [86] = MAX(IIF(seq = 7, _token, '')) OVER (PARTITION BY grp)
    , [62F] = MAX(IIF(seq = 8, _token, '')) OVER (PARTITION BY grp)
FROM rs;
```

**Output**

| 20 | 25 | 28C | 60F | 61 | 86 | 62F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D3DE7040110011E4 | 020083204 | 51/1 | C140106NAD1030073, | 1401060106DR5000,NTRF20140106-13175-0//NONREF20140106-13175-016050001844421 | /PREF/NA000520TRANSFER | C140106NAD0,00 |
| D424A100110011E4 | 020083203 | 49/1 | C140106ZAR1029873,62 | 1401060106DR5000,NTRF99999999//NONREF20140106-13175-016050001844421 | /PREF/ZA000520CATS THIRD PARTY PAYMENT | C140106ZAR0,00 |

Comment: |

Let me try you solution and get back to you. Thank you

Comment: What if I have a file with more data, Is it possible to declare it as an external source and perform the same task as your code does?

Comment: First, you can load your flat *.txt file into a staging table. And everything will work with such approach.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate how to load a flat*.txt file in to a staging area

Comment: Please ask a brand new question.

Comment: Done, I have asked another question